# Function deployment hangs at "all necessary APIs are enabled"

Tags: node.js, firebase, deployment, google-cloud-functions

When deploying the Cloud Functions to the Firebase Cloud, they take a very long time right after the log "functions: all necessary APis are enabled".

I am deploying 6 functions.

I am using node 10 since using node 8 in combination with the [URL](https://nodejs.org/api/url.html) module caused some errors that went away using node 10.

the package.json:

```
{
  "name": "functions",
  "description": "Cloud Functions for Firebase",
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "serve": "firebase serve --only functions",
    "shell": "firebase functions:shell",
    "start": "npm run shell",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-eslint": "^10.0.1",
    "cheerio": "^1.0.0-rc.2",
    "firebase-admin": "~7.0.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^2.3.0",
    "lighthouse": "^5.1.0",
    "ping": "^0.2.2",
    "puppeteer": "^1.17.0",
    "puppeteer-extra": "^2.1.3",
    "request": "^2.88.0",
    "request-promise-native": "^1.0.7",
    "url": "^0.11.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "^5.12.0",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^4.0.1"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "10"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

The deployment used to go much faster, but recently it started behaving differently.

I dont know when excactly it happened.

My questions are: 
Does anyone know what the issue might be?
If no, does anyone know how I would go about 'debugging' this issue?

Thank you.

Comment: Deployment will take as long as it takes.  There's nothing you can do to change that.  If you have problems with the Firebase CLI, you should contact Firebase support directly.  https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support

Comment: Thanks Doug, I will do that. I agree, what bugs me is that the deploytime suddenly increased by a factor of around 2 (I would say). I thought this might have to do with the switch to node10 and that being in beta.